# ASM API for type conversion

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am looking for ASM APIs to do argument type transformation for a method invocation. The main transformation is (Integer, int), (Double, double), (Float, float), which are all automatically made in Java.

For example, below code is OK because `Integer` and `Double` are automatically converted to `int` and `double` in method test before `aaa`

```
public void test(Object a, Integer b, Double c){
        aaa((String)a,b,c);
    }

public void aaa(String a, int b, double c){
        System.out.println(a.toString()+"  b:"+b+" c:"+c);
    }
```

I write ASM to do this conversion (for a general `invokevirtual` invocation) in a bytecode level, and my idea to push arguments to stack  for method `test` is:

```
   if(b instanceof Integer){ 
      {
       int t = (Integer)b.intValue();  // Sample.. Assume t is 4th local variable. 
       }
      mv.visitVarinsn(iload, 4);
   }else if(b instanceof Double){mv.visitVarinsn()}
    else if(b instanceof Byte){mv.visitVarinsn()}

   mv.visitVarInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "..", "test", methodType);
```

As there are too long if-else condition test for b's type, i am wondering whether there is already some existing ASM API can do this for me.

Comment: The Java compiler will already have generated the bytecode for you, so why do you want to massage that any further? Also, have you used `javap` to dump the bytecode?

Comment: Yes. Javac can do this..Yet, I am on doing another project, which involves dynamic bytecode generation based on existing class file. Therefore, i have to manipulate many bytecodes by myself.

Comment: Hooo... I do have to perform a lot of bytecode manipulation which I can't really wrap my head around myself... But anyway, try and see what `javac` generates when it unboxes (and `javap` is the tool for that); then replicate the bytecodes. My guess (untested) is that it will generate an `invokevirtual` on `Number::*Value`, where `*` is your wanted primitive type

Comment: Yes, i am trying to push those arguments to stack for test invokevirtual invocation. But what i want is to write a general code instead for a particular case..

Comment: [`loadArg(i)`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/commons/GeneratorAdapter.html#loadArg(int)), [`unbox(type)`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/commons/GeneratorAdapter.html#unbox(org.objectweb.asm.Type))

Comment: @Holger, thanks. This API works. But i did not use GeneratorAdapter at the beginning, because i see a comment in the ASM/helloworld example:  `// Same example with a GeneratorAdapter (more convenient but slower)`. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I wouldn’t worry about potential overhead. Generally, classes carrying unneeded features bear potential overhead but once you want or need these features this baggage isn’t overhead anymore (and re-implementing it by yourself would create the same kind of baggage). So a helloworld might be more efficient without `GeneratorAdapter` but you aren’t creating a helloworld, are you?